# How to decrypt a phrase with white space

Tags: java, encryption, whitespace, caesar-cipher

So I've been working on an encryption and decryption program, though I've been having trouble with decryption. I thought you just had to change a few values in the decryption section, but that's not working out. In addition, I've been trying to add whitespace (spaces) to the encryption and decryption process. Currently, it replaces spaces with a random letter. I thought that just adding a space to the char arrays below would fix it but it did not.

If anyone could just give me tips to solving my two problems, that'd be awesome.

```
class EncyptionandDecryption
{
char[] aEnc;
char[] aDec;
int shift;
char[] alphabet;

public EncyptionandDecryption(int c)
{
    aEnc = new char[]{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    aDec = new char[]{' ','z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'};
    shift = c;
}

public String Encryption(String phrase)
{
    String enc = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
    {
         char p = (char) (phrase.charAt(i) - 97);
         char e = (char) (((p + shift) % 26) + 97);
         enc += e;
    }
    return enc;
}

public String Decryption(String message)
{
    String dec = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
         char z = (char) (message.charAt(i) - 97);
         char p = (char) (((z - shift) % 26) + 97);
         dec += p;
    }
    return dec;
}
}
```

Comment: Why are spaces "encrypted" any differently from other characters?

Comment: Your `aEnc` and `aDec` arrays are not actually used for anything.  Did you intend to make your program use them as lookup tables instead of using addition and modulus?

Comment: Yes, I did intend to use them as lookup tables. And I thought whitespace was encrypted the same was any other character.

Comment: I assumed this is java, so I added the tag. If it is not, please [edit] your question to include the correct language tag.

Comment: Your description of your problem is not very clear. Can you [edit] your question and improve your first couple of paragraphs to precisely describe what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either a standardized encryption, which I'm sure you have reasons for not using, or using a lookup table (which it seems you planned on doing) instead. If you're having issues with the lookup table logic, I could provide some code if you so wish. These are the simpler answers.

However, you can always create a special case for spaces. Their hex value is 0x20, if I remember correctly.

As per request, here's a C# example of a lookup table. It's imperfect and for practical use requires heavy modification (It doesn't support caps, as it stands. or numbers, etc), but I hope it conveys the message. It shouldn't prove very difficult converting to Java, either.

```
    class Crypto
    {
        char[] mTable;
        char[] mReverseTable;
        public Crypto()
        {
            mTable = new char[255];
            mReverseTable = new char[255];
            List<char> lazy = new List<char>();
            Random r = new Random(123);//I'm not hardcoding a lookup table, but using a random with a predictable seed is a good alternative
            for (int i = (int)'a'; i <= (int)'z'; i++)
            {
                lazy.Add((char)i);
            }
            for (int i = (int)'a'; i <= (int)'z'; i++)
            {
                int index = r.Next(0, lazy.Count);
                mTable[i] = lazy[index];
                lazy.RemoveAt(index);
            }
            mTable[(int)']'] = ' ';//completely arbitrary to use ], but here we hardcode the value. there's a better way to do this using the random method above.
            mTable[(int)' '] = ']';
            for (int i = 0; i < mTable.Length; i++)
            {
                if (mTable[i] != '\0')
                {
                    mReverseTable[mTable[i]] = (char)i;
                }
            }
        }
        public String Encrypt(string phrase)
        {
            String enc = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
            {
                enc += mTable[phrase[i]];
            }
            return enc;
        }
        public String Decrypt(string phrase)
        {

            String enc = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
            {
                enc += mReverseTable[phrase[i]];
            }
            return enc;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind looking at your code for some help. I'll try working with the space's hex value too.